# Require help in framing logic for generating 4 digit Alphanumeric number sequence in java Expectation

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

Require help in framing logic for generating 4 digit Alphanumeric number sequence in java
Expectation

```
0001 to 9999 
A000 to A999
B000 to B999
.....
Z000 to Z999
AA00 to AA99
AB00 to AB99
BA00 to BA99
......
untill 
ZZ00 to ZZ99
```

Please help me with any suggestions/any existing logic/link.
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a correct answer, took me some time, though its not scalabel at all in comparison to other solution

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] numbers = new char['9'-'0'+1];
        for(char i = 0, ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++, i++) {
            numbers[i] = ch;
        }

        char[] chars = new char['Z'-'A' + 1];
        for(char i = 0, ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++, i++) {
            chars[i] = ch;
        }

        String[] zeroHundred = new String[numbers.length * numbers.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if(i < 10) {
                zeroHundred[i] = "0" + i;
            } else{
                zeroHundred[i] = "" + i;
            }
        }

        String[] hundredAA = new String[numbers.length * chars.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(char c : chars) {
            for(char n : numbers) {
                hundredAA[i] = "" + c + n;
                i++;
            }
        }

        String[] AAZZ = new String[chars.length * chars.length];
        i = 0;
        for(char c : chars) {
            for(char c2 : chars) {
                AAZZ[i] = "" + c + c2;
                i++;
            }
        }

        String[] all = new String[zeroHundred.length + hundredAA.length + AAZZ.length];
        System.arraycopy(zeroHundred, 0, all, 0, zeroHundred.length);
        System.arraycopy(hundredAA, 0, all, zeroHundred.length, hundredAA.length);
        System.arraycopy(AAZZ, 0, all, zeroHundred.length + hundredAA.length, AAZZ.length);

        String[] results = new String[all.length * zeroHundred.length];
        i = 0;
        for(String s1 : all) {
            for(String s2 : zeroHundred) {
                results[i] = s1 + s2;
                i++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
    }
```

i hope you will reward my efforst with opvote

Comment: Thanks Jakub, works like charm. Upvoted this answer as useful.

Answer (score -1):

there you go, i hope this is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        char[] numbers = new char['9'-'0'+1];
        for(char i = 0, ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++, i++) {
            numbers[i] = ch;
        }
        char[] chars = new char['Z'-'A' + numbers.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, chars, 0, numbers.length);

        for(char i = (char)numbers.length, ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++, i++) {
            chars[i] = ch;
        }

        String[] results = new String[chars.length * chars.length * numbers.length * numbers.length];
        int idx = 0;
        for(char c1 : chars){
            for(char c2 : chars){
                for(char c3 : numbers){
                    for(char c4 : numbers){
                        results[idx] = "" + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
                        idx++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(results));
    }
```

### edit

no i found out its not a correct answer but it can be useful, i ll come up with correct answer in a moment

Comment: sure thanks Jakub. I am also trying to work it out.